# How to add multiple formats for one style in xlwt in python?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.7, xlwt

I would like to know how can I add different formats such as for font, background color, percentage format, pallete color and more in one variable for example i'll be choosing variable style. Now in style I would like to choose format font also, background color for cell also and would like to add a percentage sign also.

I have created a variable style and have added methods for background color but on the same variable I cannot add formatting for font and add percentage sign. Please advise

style5 = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour gray25;')

style_percent = xlwt.easyxf(num_format_str='0.00%')

Above code attached shows that I have created two variable and background color and percentage sign has been formatted seperately, In actual I want to use one variable and add all this formatting for that variable, for e.g I would only create style5 and would like to add pattern and num_format_str in it. How can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this

Views.py

```
def export_styling_xls(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="users.xls"'

    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = wb.add_sheet('Styling Data') # this will make a sheet named Users Data - First Sheet
    styles = dict(
        bold = 'font: bold 1',
        italic = 'font: italic 1',
        # Wrap text in the cell
        wrap_bold = 'font: bold 1; align: wrap 1;',
        # White text on a blue background
        reversed = 'pattern: pattern solid, fore_color blue; font: color white;',
        # Light orange checkered background
        light_orange_bg = 'pattern: pattern fine_dots, fore_color white, back_color orange;',
        # Heavy borders
        bordered = 'border: top thick, right thick, bottom thick, left thick;',
        # 16 pt red text
        big_red = 'font: height 320, color red;',
    )

    for idx, k in enumerate(sorted(styles)):
        style = xlwt.easyxf(styles[k])
        ws.write(idx, 0, k)
        ws.write(idx, 1, styles[k], style)

    wb.save(response)

    return response
```